# `onChange` method in `input` doesn't fire when inside parent component making network requests in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, file-io, react-query

## Main problem

I created a component called `ImagePicker.js`, which is expected to allow the user to pick an image and then send the relevant network request. When testing this component in isolation, it works as expected. However, when I put the component inside of `Profile.js`, the `onFileChange` method that I passed into the `onChange` prop for the `input` component refuses to fire.

## Code

This problem is from an open source project my friends and I are working on called [Happiness App](https://github.com/jonathanjma/HappinessApp). Not all of this code is on the GitHub since I am testing these changes in a local branch.

`ImagePicker.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import ConfirmModal from './ConfirmModal'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
import { Modal, Spinner, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useApi } from '../contexts/ApiProvider';

export default function ImagePicker({
  showing,
  setShowing,
}) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Choose a file")
  const hiddenFileInput = useRef(null);
  const api = useApi();
  const [imgFile, setImgFile] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (imgFile == null) {
      setTitle("No file chosen")
    } else {
      console.log("changing title")
      setTitle(`File ${imgFile.name} chosen`)
    }
  }, [imgFile])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ImagePicker mounted");

    return () => {
      console.log("ImagePicker unmounting");
    };
  }, []);

  const onFileChange = (e) => {
    console.log("file changed2")
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("file changed")
    setImgFile(e.target.files[0])
  }


  const sendImageMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (value) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", value)

      return api.post("/user/pfp/", formData)
    },
  })

  const openFileChooser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("opening file chooser")
    hiddenFileInput.current.click();
  }
  const ModalBody = () =>
    sendImageMutation.isLoading ? <Spinner /> : <div className='flex flex-col'>
      <button onClick={openFileChooser}> {title} </button>
      <input ref={hiddenFileInput} className='hidden' type='file'
        onChange={onFileChange}
        accept='image/*'
        id='fileInput' />
      <p>{sendImageMutation.isError ? "Error submitting file" : ""}</p>
      <p>{sendImageMutation.isSuccess ? "Successfully sent request" : ""}</p>
    </div>


  const handleClose = () => {
    setShowing(false);
  }
  const handleConfirm = () => {
    sendImageMutation.mutate(imgFile);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sendImageMutation.isSuccess) {
      setShowing(false);
    }
  }, [sendImageMutation])
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={showing} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>Select an image from your files.</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body><ModalBody /></Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={handleConfirm}>
            Continue
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>

  )
}
```

`Profile.js`:

```
import Stat from "../components/statGraphs/Stat";
import Graph from "../components/statGraphs/Graph";
import Histories from "../components/happinessHistory/Histories";
import DayPreview from "../components/statGraphs/DayPreview";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { useUser } from "../contexts/UserProvider";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Spinner, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  PrevWeekData,
  GetCountHappiness,
} from "../components/happinessHistory/GetHappinessData";
import { useApi } from "../contexts/ApiProvider";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ImagePicker from "../components/ImagePicker";

export default function Profile() {
  const me = useUser();
  const userID = useParams().userID;
  const today = new Date();
  const todayString = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  const api = useApi();
  const [imgPickerShowing, setImgPickerShowing] = useState(false)

  // console.log(userID);
  // console.log(me.user.user.id);
  // console.log(parseInt(userID) === me.user.user.id);

  const {
    isLoading: isLoadingU,
    data: user,
    error: errorU,
    refetch: refetchU,
  } = useQuery(
    "get user from user id",
    () => api.get("/user/" + userID).then((res) => res.data),
    { fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network" }
  );
  const [pageLoading, setPageLoading] = useState(true);

  // gets user groups (only shown if viewing own profile)
  const {
    isLoading: isLoadingUG,
    data: dataUG,
    error: errorUG,
    refetch: refetchUG,
  } = useQuery("get user groups", () =>
    api.get("/user/groups").then((res) => res.data)
  );

  const [isLoadingH, dataH, errorH, refetchH] = PrevWeekData(true, userID);
  const [isLoadingC, dataC, errorC, refetchC] = GetCountHappiness(4, userID);

  // refetches user when ID changed
  useEffect(() => {
    const refetchAll = async () => {
      setPageLoading(true);
      console.log("refetching!!");
      await refetchU();
      await refetchH();
      await refetchC();
      await refetchUG();
      setPageLoading(false);
      // setPageLoading(false);
    };
    refetchAll();
  }, [userID]);

  let userCreated = "";
  if (user !== undefined && user.created !== null) {
    // formatted date into array
    let forDa = new Date(user.created)
      .toLocaleDateString("sv")
      .substring(0, 10)
      .split("-");
    userCreated =
      "Member since " + forDa[1] + "/" + forDa[2] + "/" + forDa[0].substring(2);
  }
  const [dShow, setDShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>


      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
        {isLoadingUG ||
          isLoadingC ||
          isLoadingH ||
          isLoadingU ||
          pageLoading ? (
          <Spinner animation="border" />
        ) : (
          <>
            {errorUG || errorU || errorC || errorH ? (
              <p className="text-md font-medium text-raisin-600 m-3">
                Error: Could not load information.
              </p>
            ) : (
              <>
                <ImagePicker
                  showing={imgPickerShowing}
                  setShowing={setImgPickerShowing} />
                <div className="lg:w-3/4 sm:w-full">
                  <div>
                    <p className="text-center text-4xl font-medium m-2 text-raisin-600">
                      Profile
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center">
                    <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center min-w-[330px] max-w-[600px] min-h-[200px] mx-4 my-2 bg-cultured-50 rounded-xl shadow-lg space-y-2">
                      <div className="relative flex flex-wrap justify-center w-full bg-buff-300 rounded-t-xl">
                        <div className="absolute -sm:absolute sm:relative left-4 top-4 sm:flex items-center md:px-4 md:w-1/3 sm:mx-4">
                          <img
                            className="mb-4 justify-center max-w-[65px] max-h-[65px] md:min-h-[125px] md:max-h-[125px] md:min-w-[125px] md:max-w-[125px] block mx-auto rounded-full sm:mx-0 sm:shrink-0"
                            src={user.profile_picture}
                            alt="profile"
                            onClick={() => { setImgPickerShowing(true) }}
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-full justify-end sm:w-1/2 py-2 px-4">
                          <p className="text-center text-2xl font-medium m-2 text-raisin-600">
                            {user.username}
                          </p>
                          <p className="text-center text-raisin-600">
                            {userCreated}
                          </p>
                          <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center @container">
                            <div className="justify-center">
                              {parseInt(userID) === me.user.user.id ? (
                                <>
                                  <Link to="/groups" className="no-underline">
                                    <p className="text-center text-raisin-600 text-md font-medium m-2 sm:w-full">
                                      Groups: {dataUG.length}
                                    </p>
                                  </Link>
                                </>
                              ) : (
                                <></>
                              )}
                              {/* <p className="text-lg text-center text-raisin-600 m-2">
                        3
                      </p> */}
                            </div>
                            {/* <div className="w-3/8">
                      <p className="text-md text-raisin-600 font-medium text-center m-2">
                        Weekly Average
                      </p>
                      <p className="text-lg text-raisin-600 text-center m-2">
                        {5.75}
                      </p>
                    </div> */}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex m-4">
                        {dataC.length === 0 ? (
                          <p className="text-md font-medium text-raisin-600 m-3">
                            No happiness data available.
                          </p>
                        ) : (
                          <>
                            <div className="space-y-2 px-2 md:px-4">
                              {todayString.substring(0, 10) ===
                                dataC[0].timestamp ? (
                                <p className="text-md text-raisin-600 font-semibold text-center">
                                  Today's Happiness
                                </p>
                              ) : (
                                <p className="text-md text-raisin-600 font-semibold text-center">
                                  Recent Happiness
                                </p>
                              )}
                              <p className="text-2xl text-rhythm-500 font-medium text-center">
                                {dataC[0].value.toFixed(1)}
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            {dataC[0].comment ? (
                              <>
                                <DayPreview
                                  open={dShow}
                                  setOpen={setDShow}
                                  data={[dataC[0]]}
                                  users={[user]}
                                />
                                <div
                                  className="space-y-2 px-2 md:px-4 md:mx-4"
                                  onClick={() => setDShow(true)}
                                >
                                  <p className="text-md text-raisin-600 font-semibold text-center">
                                    Comment
                                  </p>
                                  <p className="line-clamp-3 -md:line-clamp-3 text-md text-rhythm-500 font-medium text-center">
                                    {dataC[0].comment}
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </>
                            ) : (
                              <></>
                            )}
                          </>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center">
                      {dataH.length === 0 ? (
                        <p className="text-xl font-medium text-raisin-600 m-3">
                          Data not available for selected period.
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        <>
                          <p className="mt-4 sm:w-full text-center font-medium text-2xl text-raisin-600">
                            Weekly Statistics
                          </p>
                          <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center mx-2 md:ml-4 max-w-[400px] max-h-[400px]">
                            <Graph data={dataH} users={[user]} time="Weekly" />
                          </div>
                          <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center md:max-w-[205px] sm:max-w-[400px] mr-2">
                            <Stat
                              data={dataH.map((f) => f.value)}
                              key={0}
                              val={0}
                            />
                            <Stat
                              data={dataH.map((f) => f.value)}
                              key={1}
                              val={1}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="justify-center lg:w-1/4 w-full max-w-[550px]">
                  <div>
                    <p className="text-center text-4xl font-medium m-2 text-raisin-600">
                      History
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  {dataC.length === 0 ? (
                    <p className="text-md font-medium text-raisin-600 m-3">
                      Data not available for selected period.
                    </p>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <Histories dataList={dataC} userList={[user]} />
                      <div className="m-3 flex justify-center">
                        <Link to={"/history/" + userID}>
                          <Button variant="outline-secondary">show all</Button>
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

## What I've tried

I've tried just commenting out code in `Profile.js` until it worked, and what I noticed is that any code that makes a network request in the main function body will cause the `onChange` to fail and not be fired. I'm not getting any console logs for the method and it is just not being activated at all. I've also tried removing the `display: none` from the ImagePicker but that did not work (I wasn't expecting it to). I think the issue is that when the file explorer is opened, the page rerenders which causes the network requests to be fired, which for some reason disconnects the file explorer from the image picker component or something? I am very confused as to why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated. I also tried using a `useEffect` snippet to see of the image picker was being dismounted, but from the logs I could tell it seemed to be still mounted. I am referring to this part of the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ImagePicker mounted");

    return () => {
      console.log("ImagePicker unmounting");
    };
  }, []);
```

I have been struggling on this problem for a long while and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.